# Implementing Roles in ASP.NET web forms application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-roles

This might be a stupid question to ask but I am kind of a confuse here I am working on an ASP.NET web forms application and I need to implement roles base access to users.

This application is working with Active Directory so there is no login forms and form base authentication and I can't use User.Identity to check the roles. I am getting roles from a stored procedure like 1 for admin 2 for user and I want to know if there is a way to implement it generically like set some attributes to add in the controls to show and hide them instead of go and implement if conditions in every form.

I am not sure if I presented my point clearly here or not but please let me know if you get the idea of what I am trying to say. Thank you.

Comment: Can you inherit your webforms from a custom class? 
If so than you can make base class explicitly for your roles and let that classes inherited by `System.Web.UI.Page`

Comment: @Jackboys I think I can but I didn't see the point how it is going to help?

Comment: Let say you have Employee role and Supervisor role, for all Employee role page you inherit by `EmployeePage` class and all Supervisor role page by `SupervisorPage`. Now `EmployeePage` and `SupervisorPage` will be inherited from `System.Web.UI.Page` 
and in `EmployeePage` and `SupervisorPage` `Page_Load` function you can place your authorization.

Comment: And for Authentication, you can call that SPROC from `Page_Load` and check the role, can be a naive solution, but make the job done

Comment: but for that case didn't I need to create multiple classes for each role ? and I have one page like which shows results of students and both employee and supervisor can see it but only supervisor can edit it how its going to work with that.

Comment: Yes, for both roles you can make another class and control the visibility according to your need